# How to get kubernetes service external ip dynamically inside manifests file?

Tags: kubernetes

We are creating a deployment in which the command needs the IP of the pre-existing service pointing to a statefulset. Below is the manifest file for the deployment. Currently, we are manually entering the service external IP inside this deployment manifest. Now we would like it to auto-populate during runtime. Is there a way to achieve this dynamically using environment variables or another way?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-api
  namespace: app-api
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-api
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app-api
        image: asia-south2-docker.pkg.dev/rnd20/app-api/api:09
        command: ["java","-jar","-Dallow.only.apigateway.request=false","-Dserver.port=8084","-Ddedupe.searcher.url=http://10.10.0.6:80","-Dspring.cloud.zookeeper.connect-string=10.10.0.6:2181","-Dlogging$.file.path=/usr/src/app/logs/springboot","/usr/src/app/app_api/dedupe-engine-components.jar",">","/usr/src/app/out.log"]
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 8084
            httpHeaders:
            - name: Custom-Header
              value: ""
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 60
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4016
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1
            memory: "2Gi"
          requests:
            cpu: 1
            memory: "2Gi"
```

**NOTE**: The IP in question here is the Internal load balancer IP, i.e. the external IP for the service and the service is in a different namespace. Below is the manifest for the same

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app
  namespace: app
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  selector:
    app: app
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: container
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
```

Comment: you can also `service.namespace` will return the IP or the application can work on IP only?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following command instead:

```
command:
  - /bin/bash
  - -c
  - |-
    set -exuo pipefail

    ip=$(dig +search +short servicename.namespacename)

    exec java -jar -Dallow.only.apigateway.request=false -Dserver.port=8084 -Ddedupe.searcher.url=http://$ip:80 -Dspring.cloud.zookeeper.connect-string=$ip:2181 -Dlogging$.file.path=/usr/src/app/logs/springboot /usr/src/app/app_api/dedupe-engine-components.jar > /usr/src/app/out.log
```

It first resolves the ip address using `dig` (if you don't have `dig` in your image - you need to substitute it with something else you have), then `exec`s your original `java` command.

As of today I'm not aware of any "native" kubernetes way to provide IP meta information directly to the pod.

Comment: Hi, zerkms thanks for your suggestion. this works like a charm but only for the clusterIP/Internal IP of the service but we need to find the external IP of the service which is an internal load balancer.

Comment: @NitinGarg without further details it's hard to help. There are million different technologies to implement load-balancing. Hence determining the external LB IP would be technology-specific.

Comment: please let me know what more details you need. I will update the question itself. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: "The IP in question here is the load balancer Internal IP" --- this needs all details you have. What is "LB internal IP", how LB is implemented, etc etc

Comment: Updated the question as requested. Please let me know if you need any more info

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure they exist before, and you deploy into the same namespace, you can read them from environment variables. It's documented here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#environment-variables.

> When a Pod is run on a Node, the kubelet adds a set of environment variables for each active Service. It adds {SVCNAME}_SERVICE_HOST and {SVCNAME}_SERVICE_PORT variables, where the Service name is upper-cased and dashes are converted to underscores. It also supports variables (see makeLinkVariables) that are compatible with Docker Engine's "legacy container links" feature.
>
> For example, the Service redis-master which exposes TCP port 6379 and has been allocated cluster IP address 10.0.0.11, produces the following environment variables:
>
> ```
> REDIS_MASTER_SERVICE_HOST=10.0.0.11
> REDIS_MASTER_SERVICE_PORT=6379
> REDIS_MASTER_PORT=tcp://10.0.0.11:6379
> REDIS_MASTER_PORT_6379_TCP=tcp://10.0.0.11:6379
> REDIS_MASTER_PORT_6379_TCP_PROTO=tcp
> REDIS_MASTER_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT=6379
> REDIS_MASTER_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR=10.0.0.11
> ```

Note, those wont update after the container is started.

Comment: @zerkms, good point, I have added that.

Comment: Thanks, Fool ... this helped me to gain knowledge but did not serve the purpose since my service is in a different namespace.